# Swap the head of the linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I had heard this question from my friend who attended an interview recently:

Given the head of the linked list, Write a function to swap the head with the next element in the linked list and return the pointer to the new head.

Ex:

```
i/p: 1->2,3,4,5 (the given head is 1)
o/p: 2->1,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;
```

then the solution might look something like

```
struct node *next = head->next;
if(next == NULL) return head; // nothing to swap
head->next = next->next;
next->next = head;
head = next;
return next;
```

Comment: Thanks ! Though i am not sure about the optimization.

Comment: What do you mean by optimization here? It is a swapping operation of pointers done in 3 statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct node* head;

struct node *tmp1,*tmp2;
tmp1=head; // save first node pointer
tmp2=head->next->next; // save third node pointer
head=head->next; // Move Head to the second node
head->next=tmp1; // swap
head->next->next=tmp2; // Restore the link to third node
```